# Generate lists that satisfy a condition in an efficient way

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-review

The following code produces lists of sublists with maximum length 5 that shuffle zeros around an ordered list (here `{1,2}`). It produces all permutations while keeping the ordering of the list `{1,2}` within the permutations:

```
mylst[K_]:=Select[Drop[Tuples[{0,1,2},K],1],Total[#]==3&&Count[#,1]==1&&#[[Position[#,x_/;!TrueQ[x==0],{1},1,Heads->False][[1,1]]]]!=2&]
mylst /@ Range[5]
```

Each of `mylst[K]` generates $K(K-1)/2$ terms.

Is there a better way to code `mylst`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for fun, here is the pattern based version

```
mylst2[K_] := ReplaceList[
  ConstantArray[0, K],
  {a___, x_, b___, y_, c___} :> {a, 1, b, 2, c}
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified version! Seems really compact way to do the same task!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu It's neat, but I say "for fun" because Carlo's solution is the better :)

Comment: From what aspect? I have only tried to time them. With $K=100$ (just for fun), yours is 0.015600 sec and Carlo's is 0.109200. What I will ever use is only up to about $K=15$, in which case, both use 0. sec with `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Surprising! Rule based solutions often have poor complexity, I guess in this case it works...

Comment: Mathematica has surprised me in various ways over the past 3 months while I am self learning.

Comment: `mylst2[200]; // AbsoluteTiming` (yours) VS `mylst3[200]; // AbsoluteTiming` (Carlo's), it's about `{0.078000, Null}` VS `{0.780001, Null}`. Nearly *10* times.

Comment: No, I think your solution is better Pickett. I forfeit!

Comment: @Carlo Alright then :D ty

Comment: @Pickett I actually want to keep the order, so I have added a `Reverse[ youcode]`. Do you know if that's possible to control the order from the way it's constructed? So I dont have to reverse it?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu It isn't.

Answer (score 5):

```
mylst2[K_] := Map[
    ReplacePart[#, FirstPosition[#, 2] -> 1] &,
    Permutations[PadRight[{2, 2}, K]]
]
```

This might not be what you want for K == 0. But it has much better complexity (quadratic vs exponential).

Comment: That will do! I dont really use the case $K=0$.